# session array variable fatfree

Tags: arrays, variables, session, fat-free-framework

i am playing with my own way of storing user selected items on a simple shop system which uses the hidden int values( primary id for item) from a form.
On each  selection i test to see if session variable has been set if not:

```
 if ($f3->get('SESSION.item') == NULL)
         {
        $f3->set('SESSION.item',array($itemFromPost ));
                ...
}
```

if it has been set then i push next selection :

```
$f3->push('SESSION.item',$itemFromPost);
```

it look promising and i can get count of items like:

```
$total = (count ( $f3->get('SESSION.item')
```

Also i can do this:

```
echo $f3->get('SESSION.item[0]');
```

what doesn't work is when i want to run through items:

```
for ($i= 0; $i <= TotalCountValueMinus1; $i++ ) 
   {

   echo $f3->get('SESSION.item[$i]');

   }
```

how do i do this?

Comment: It should work. You probably have a typo somewhere. You can also use `foreach($f3->get('SESSION.item') as $item) echo $item;`.

Comment: ok cheers xfra35 , it works your way

Comment: I got it: your code probably doesn't work because it contains single instead of [double quotes](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

Comment: @xfra35 i would like to keep this thread open and post questions as they come up in my journey to getting a simple cart system going for $f3 ; if you can pop back time to time to see how i am getting on that would be great (my progress is not likely to be faster than fortnightly) Then i could string together code & out  a simple tutorial for those like me that can get their head around basic PHP but not the $f3 docs on basket without a "in easy steps type tutorial".

Comment: The dedicated [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/f3-framework) is more appropriate for this kind of purpose. You can post all your questions as they come up and people will help you there.

Comment: actually thats a big help about the double quotes because i got variable $t not recognized and not highlighted blue with medit text editor  , but ok with double quotes for     :  $f3->clear ('SESSION.item[$t]'); but what about the docs everything is single quotes eg                                                                                                   $f3->mset(
    array(
        'foo'=>'bar',
        'baz'=>123
    )
);

Comment: This has nothing to do with the framework. This is how PHP works. Just compare the results of `'var= \r\n $var'` and `"var= \r\n $var"`. Single quotes are not interpreted while double quotes are.